# Scanning for new disks attached using virtio?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, block-device, virtio

I can successfully attach disks to a running KVM instance using `virsh attach-disk`...

```
virsh attach-disk node-1 /dev/vg_lunsr/lun1  vdb
Disk attached successfully
```

...but these new devices aren't seen by the guest without a reboot, which almost defeats the purpose of dynamic attachment.  If these were SCSI devices I would use e.g. `/sys/class/scsi_host/host0/scan` to request the SCSI drivers to scan for new devices.  Is there an equivalent capability for the virtio block driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it mostly depends on what distro is running inside the guest. On Debian/Ubuntu, you certainly want to load this kernel module:

```
modprobe acpiphp
```

and then try to hot plug your devices. It will appear without guest reboot. You can find more information about hot plugging in libvirt [here](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Hotadd_pci_devices)

Answer (score 0):

This most likely depends on your guests kernel/KVM/udev version.
Just tried it with centos 6.3 and as soon as i added the disk.
Device /dev/vdb was available on the running guest.